# Kotlin Coroutines wait for job to complete

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I have a ViewModel. Inside it, I have a function which fetches some images from the phones internal storage.

Before the fetching is complete it is exposing livedata in mainactivity. How to make coroutines to wait for the task to complete and expose the live data.

```
 // This is my ViewModel

 private val _image = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<File>>()
 val images: LiveData<ArrayList<File>> get() = _image

fun fetchImage(){
    val file = Path.imageDirectory  //  returns a directory where images are stored
    val files = arrayListOf<File>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.walk().forEach {
                    if (it.isFile && it.path.endsWith("jpeg")) {
                        files.add(it)
                    }
                }
            }

            files.sortByDescending { it.lastModified() } // sort the files to get newest 
                                                         // ones at top of the list
        }
    }

    _image.postValue(files)
}
```

Is there any other approach to make this code much faster by any other methods?

Comment: what's the problem using `_image.postValue(files)` inside `launch`? also you can use `.invokeOnCompletion {  }`

Comment: You can wait for job only when function is suspendable, i.e. Using the suspend keyword.

Comment: @IR42 what's the problem using _image.postValue(files) inside launch?  yes it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
fun fetchImage() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val file = Path.imageDirectory  //  returns a directory where images are stored
    val files = arrayListOf<File>()

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.walk().forEach {
                if (it.isFile && it.path.endsWith("jpeg")) {
                    files.add(it)
                }
            }
        }

        files.sortByDescending { it.lastModified() } // sort the files to get newest
        // ones at top of the list
    }

    _image.value = files
}
```